# ODataProperties NextLink is Null

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an OData Web API service using .NET 4.5. It has a WebApi controller derived from another controller I made myself.

```
public class AerodromoController : BaseController
{
    public PageResult<Aerodromo> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Aerodromo> options)
    {
        return Paging(Store.Aerodromo.All(), options);
    }
}
```

This 'Paging' method is from BaseController and do as follow:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public PageResult<T> Paging<T>(IQueryable<T> query, ODataQueryOptions<T> options)
    {
        IQueryable Data;
        if (options.Top != null)
        {
            Data = options.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = options.Top.Value });
        }
        else
        {
            Data = options.ApplyTo(query);
        }

        return new PageResult<T>(
            Data as IEnumerable<T>,
            Request.ODataProperties().NextLink,
            query.Count());
    }
}
```

After firing an ajax request like that:

```
$.getJSON('acompanhamento/aerodromo?$' + encodeURI("top=20"))
```

I do get the top 20 entities and the count. But the nextPageLink is null. This is kinda weird, cause the following code works. What could be happening?

```
public class AerodromoController : BaseController
{
    public PageResult<Aerodromo> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Aerodromo> options)
    {
        var Data = options.ApplyTo(Store.Aerodromo.All(), new ODataQuerySettings()
        {
            PageSize = 20
        });
        return new PageResult<Aerodromo>(
            Data as IEnumerable<Aerodromo>,
            Request.ODataProperties().NextLink,
            Store.Aerodromo.All().Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Eduardo, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
if (options.Top != null)
    {
        Data = options.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = options.Top.Value });
    }
```

If you say on the client side you want 20 results ($top=20) and on the server side you set the max page size to 20, the user of the api won't get a nextPageLink, because he got what he wanted.

You get a nextPageLink, if the client wants more than the max PageSize you have set on the server side.
Also I think you need to validate the options of the ODataQueryOptions.

Don't set the PageSize to `options.Top.Value`!

```
var allowedOptions = new ODataValidationSettings
        {
            AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.Filter | AllowedQueryOptions.Skip |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy | AllowedQueryOptions.InlineCount
        };

options.Validate(allowedOptions);

var Data = options.ApplyTo(Store.Aerodromo.All(), new ODataQuerySettings()
    {
        PageSize = 10 // now you get a next page link when u say $top=20
    });
```